# The following files didn't self register or unregister: Error0x0

Tags: dll

Hi I'm using Windows 2008 Enterprise R2 VM  and when I reinstall Delmia Process engineer I get:

The following files didn't self register or unregister:
   C:\DELMIA\PPRServer\win_b64\code\bin\ergoplandoimpl.dll
   Error 0x0

to continue click OK; other wise click Cancel

If I click OK to continue, the program doesn't install correctly, and then won't run.

When i get the error, if I try to regsvr32 ergoplandoimpl.dll, I get an error:

The module "ergoplandoimpl.dll" may not be compatible with the version of windows that you are running. Check if the module is compatible with x86 (32bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe

I have 5 copies of the VM, just one VM has this error after I Uninstalled it.  I have also reinstalled VC redist 2005, 2008 , 2010.  Beside doing a windows repair what else can I do?

Comment: Have you called Delmia for support yet?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Delmia issue.  I can install Delmia Process Engineer using teh same installer on the other VMs without issue. When using depncdancy walker I get MSVCR90.DLL as a yellow question mark.  It claims the system cannot find the file specified.  I have reinstalled vcresdist 2005, 2008 and 2010, with no luck.

Comment: I did look at Delmia's KB, it appears that someone else has the issue.  I'll look for support and see if they have answers.